# append rows from another dataframe

Tags: dask

I am using dask dataframe

When I do

```
df = train_df.append(test_df)
```

it throws

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 2958, in append
    return super(DataFrame, self).append(other)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1691, in append
    return concat([self, other], join='outer', interleave_partitions=False)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py", line 630, in concat
    raise ValueError('All inputs have known divisions which '
ValueError: All inputs have known divisions which cannot be concatenated in order. Specify interleave_partitions=True to ignore order
```

What is the right way of doing that? I want to append rows from test_df to train_df where they have same set of columns.

Comment: I am currently struggling with this too - it looks like the documentation is incorrect for the append function.


Looking at the source, the append function doesn't take any kwargs: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/core.py#L1682


However, the documentation does list some: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.append


Related dask issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4217

Comment: Have you tried using `dd.concat`?